# Server only prints messages from the most recently connected client

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to create a server that accepts multiple clients. The clients can send messages to the server, and the server prints these messages. My code below produces a weird result where only the most recent connection has its messages accepted and printed by the server.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import _thread

HOST = "192.168.1.84"
PORT = 5000


def client_thread(conn):
    welcome_message = "Connected to server " + HOST + ":" + str(PORT) + "\n"
    conn.send(welcome_message.encode("ascii"))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        message = data.decode("ascii")
        if not data:
            break
        print("(" + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]) + ") " + message)
    connection.close()


with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    try:
        server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        server_socket.listen(10)
        print("Server hosted on " + HOST + ":" + str(PORT) + "\n")
        while True:
            connection, address = server_socket.accept()
            _thread.start_new_thread(client_thread, (connection,))
            print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))

    except socket.error as error_message:
        print("Error: " + str(error_message))
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.1.84"
PORT = 5000

with socket.socket() as client_socket:
    try:
        client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
        data = client_socket.recv(2048)
        print(data.decode("ascii"))
        while True:
            message = input()
            data = message.encode("ascii")
            client_socket.send(data)
    except socket.error as error_message:
        print("Error: " + str(error_message))
```

**Problem Output Behavior:**

Client 1 can connect to the server and send messages. The server receives and prints these messages fine.

Now when Client 2 connects to the server, Client 1's messages no longer is sent to the server. Now only Client 2 can send messages to the server and have it printed fine.

To further carry this out, Client 3 connects to the server. Now both Client 1's and Client 2's messages aren't sent to the server, only Client 3's messages are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `client_thread` function has some issues.  `conn` is the connection passed to the thread, but `connection` and `address` are being read from the global namespace.  Instead, use the connection passed in and pass the `address` as well, so each thread is only referring to local variables for the connection/address pair it is responsible for:

```
def client_thread(conn,addr):
    welcome_message = "Connected to server " + HOST + ":" + str(PORT) + "\n"
    conn.send(welcome_message.encode("ascii"))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        message = data.decode("ascii")
        if not data:
            break
        print("(" + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]) + ") " + message)
    conn.close()
```

In the main code:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(client_thread, (connection,address))
```